# Как запретить поисковым ботам просматривать все папки кроме одной?

Tags: php, robots.txt

Как запретить поисковым ботам просматривать все папки кроме одной?

Вот как расположены папки:

`qqq1` - коренная директория

```
qqq1----www1
        eeee2
        tttt3---index.php
```

Нужно запретить все папки кроме `tttt3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /tttt3
```

Comment: Вы уверены что это прокатит? Я проверял этот варинат не работает. Может ... еще раз проверю.

Comment: @gilo1212, Уверен

Comment: Страненько, не хочет работать или я ппц... Робот говорит что нету доступа.

Comment: вроде заработало...хм.....не уверен на 100

Comment: index.php в `qqq1` не видет.

Comment: То есть при указании просто домена, ничего не видет не видет страницу

Comment: Проблема в чёт то другом. В webmaster.yandex сделал так же как у Вас https://i.gyazo.com/fb61a5e44e944c9c129bb34de4a90039.png